# Swimming pool / facility vs piscina

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones

En alemán tenemos dos palabras:

1. "Schwimmbad" - se trata de toda la instalación con casa, vestuarios, césped y piscinas.
2. "Schwimmbecken" - donde se nada en ella

Tengo dos traducciones:

1. piscina
2. pileta de natación/pileta

Ayer en mi clase de español quise explicarle a mi profesora:
"My swimming pool (the whole facility) consists of a small lake and different pools" => "Mi piscina consiste en un pequeño lago y diferentes piscinas ???"

Incluso en inglés no funciona tan bien, ya que toda la instalación utiliza la misma palabra que la piscina en la que se nada. Aquí puedes ver las instalaciones: https://www.aqwa-walldorf.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Lageplan.jpg (Nota: Lageplan = Plano/mapa del sitio)

¿Cómo lo traduciría?

Ella (de Argentina) recomienda la palabra *"olla"* para la piscina en la que se está nadando.

Corrección: "Olla" describe un pequeño lago rodeado de rocas, como el de mi complejo de piscinas.  Como aquí: https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/50/06/4f/pozo-del-indio.jpg

Comment: "olla"? soy argentino y jamás escuché a alguien usar "olla" en este contexto. "Olla" es un recipiente de cocina donde hierves agua o cocinas.

Comment: Yo tampoco lo he encontrado ("olla") y tendré que volver a preguntar. Lo que sí he encontrado es "alberca", como "Alberca Estructural" y "Alberca Inflable".

Comment: "alberca" es muy mexicano, hasta donde sé, no se usa ni en España ni en Sudamerica . Me parece que piscina se entiende en cualquier pais hispanoparlante (aunque en Argentina se diga pileta). No conozco ninguna palabra que se refiera a toda la instalación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Alemán habitualmente suele crear palabras únicas a partir la unión de otras, algo que no sucede con tanta asiduidad en los demás idiomas. Si aplicas el caso de la pregunta a cualquier palabra en Alemán producto de la unión de varios conceptos, el listado es infinito y respuestas con resultados únicos más bien pocas.

No creo que exista una única palabra en Español para lo que podríamos llamar *zona de baño* o *jardín con piscina*; frases que definen un área concreta con más elementos que un simple receptáculo para nadar.

Comment: Buen punto, sólo combinamos los sustantivos. Esto da lugar a muchas palabras específicas.

Answer (score 4):

**Cuestión**: Swimming pool / facility vs piscina. ¿Cómo lo traduciría?

---

Depende mucho de las localizaciones y el nombre regional o local empleado para este tipo de instalaciones. Así estos "complejos", como el indicado en el enlace, son muy habituales, al menos, en el sur de España. Normalmente a su carácter ocio-deportivo le sigue el nombre con el que se le bautiza y por el que es realmente conocido.

**Algunas de las designaciones más habituales son**;

- Parque Deportivo (Nombre)
- Parque Recreativo y Acuático (Nombre) o de (Ciudad más cercana)
- Complejo Recreativo de (Nombre)
- (Nombre) Complejo Deportivo
- Complejo Deportivo-Recreativo (Nombre)
- Complejo (Nombre)
- Instalación recreativa-deportiva (pública o privada) de (Nombre)
- Instalaciones Deportivas (Nombre)
- Instalaciones del Parque Deportivo-Recreativo (Nombre)
- Centro Deportivo-Recreativo (Nombre)
- Club Deportivo (Nombre)
- Equipamiento Recreativo y Deportivo de (Nombre)
- Zona de Equipamiento Deportivo de (Nombre)

---

Para nosotros, la misma piscina y todo aquello que le rodea puede estar asociado al ocio, a la natación o al deporte en general, ya sea en un "Pabellón Cubierto" o al aire libre, y es normal encontrar este tipo de denominaciones, que por otro lado son las más habituales, aunque como digo, varía según los lugares. Sin embargo, a nivel Europeo no funcionan los apelativos "pila", "pileta" "alberca" u "olla", pues son voces anticuadas que no evocan el número de actividades en general que se pueden realizar en este tipo de centros.

En mi opinión y de forma personal, para nombrar a este tipo de instalaciones elegiría el nombre de "**Complejo + (Nombre)**". Por ejemplo "**Complejo Largeplan**". En este ejemplo, el mismo nombre ya está indicando que es un lugar (**Complejo**, significa lugar con instalaciones, que pueden ser interiores, exteriores o mixtas, destinadas al ocio donde poder realizar actividades de distinta índole). Si a eso le añades, por ejemplo, la palabra "planes"-"largos" (Largeplan), indica una localización donde familias y personas de distintas edades pueden encontrar multitud de "planes" y "actividades" donde disfrutar de su tiempo libre, ya sea como descanso o deportivo. Otra idea sería utilizar el nombre del lago y con ello denominar a todo el "Complejo Deportivo".

En fin, todas estas opciones son habituales, múltiples y correctas, aunque en concreto y a lo que te refieres en el enlace, personalmente lo traduciría simplemente como "**Complejo Deportivo**", y en el caso de que tenga carácter eminentemente privado "**Club Deportivo**".

Comment: Gracias por el gran resumen de posibilidades.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que la traducción que mejor encaja es **instalación deportiva**.

Más específicamente, y atendiendo al número de deportes que se practican en dicha instalación, tendremos ([texto de la Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instalaci%C3%B3n_deportiva)):

> **Espacio deportivo**: es el espacio donde se desarrolla una actividad deportiva específica, por ejemplo una sala de artes marciales, la pista de carreras en un estadio de atletismo, un campo de tiro al plato o una pista de snowboard.

> **Complejo deportivo**: se trata de dos o más instalaciones deportivas diferentes ubicadas en un recinto común y con fácil acceso entre cada una de sus partes; funcionan independientemente entre sí y se conocen generalmente bajo una misma denominación.

Comment: Gracias, es muy útil

Answer (score 1):

En Latinoamérica la palabra piscina se refiere únicamente a "Schwimmbecken". En inglés, su significado estricto seria "pool", aunque no es raro que se use también "Swimming pool" para diferenciarla del juego de pool (billiard table) al cual se hace referencia generalmente con la palabra "pool" (billar).